# Assuming i.i.d. sequence of variable when testing for autocorrelation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, autocorrelation

In Tsay's Analysis of Financial time series he is assuming an independent, identical distribution (iid) when testing the hypothesis of

$H_0: \rho_\kappa=0$

However isn't assuming iid exactly what we are testing against? A positive autocorrelation meaning that the distributions at least are not independent?

Is this still a meaningful test then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little difficult to comment without a precise citation from Tsay, but under $H_0$ we do assume/hypothesize i.i.d'ness. This is used e.g. when deriving the distribution of the test statistic under $H_0$ against which we evaluate the observed test statistic. If is similar to how one assumes/hypothesizes equality of the mean to a constant in a $t$-test as $H_0$ and then derives the distribution of the $t$-statistic under $H_0$ (it is a $t$-distribution).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I'm confused about is the assumption. "If $\{r_t\}$ is a stationary Gausian series satisfying $\rho_j=0$ the t ratio is asymptotically distributed as a standard normal random vairable." But we are testing for dependency? Isn't that assumption violated implicitly?

Comment: @Anders, there is no dependence under $H_0$, and we use the knowledge of the distribution of the test statistic under $H_0$ to test for violations of $H_0$ such as nonzero autocorrelation. So it is OK.